# Parsing JSON with JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to parse a JSON, I am already parsing the first part of the record but I am having a problem with a sub record. This is my code:

```
  List<JToken> results = new List<JToken>();
        List<JToken> results2 = new List<JToken>();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            results = JObject.Parse(result).SelectToken("record").ToList();
        }
        List<Record> users = new List<Record>();
        foreach (JObject token in results)
        {
            Record user = new Record();
            user.id = Int32.Parse(token["id"].ToString());
            user.full_name = token["full_name"].ToString();
            user.email = token["email"].ToString();

            //role.RoleName = token.SelectToken("name").ToString();

        }
```

That's working perfectly but I have issues parsin a string that's a bit deeper. This is the JSON:

```
{
  "record": [
   {
  "id": 2,
  "institution_id": 1,
  "full_name": "",
  "email": "",
  "role_id": 2,
  "created": "2015-01-13 01:18:52.370379",
  "updated": "2015-01-22 23:58:44.103636",
  "branch_id": 1,
  "Branch_by_branch_id": {
    "id": 1,
    "institution_id": 1,
    "branch_name": "Test Branch"
  }
}
```

]
}

I want to get the "branch_name" inside Branch_by_branch_id. How can I access it with Jobject?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Are you sure you copy/pasted it correctly?

Comment: `token["Branch_by_branch_id"]["branch_name"]` should do the trick, will test when the JSON is fixed.

Comment: Tested that out DBC, gave me a "
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " error

Comment: @LordRelix - just tried `var branch_name = token["Branch_by_branch_id"]["branch_name"].ToString()` and it worked.  Did you do something different?

Comment: Of course, checking for missing records is reasonable: `if (token["Branch_by_branch_id"] != null && token["Branch_by_branch_id"]["branch_name"] != null)`

Comment: I verified and it should have a value. The JSON is giving me data, the token names match the JSON. So weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON is this

```
{
    "record": [
        {
            "id": 26,
            "full_name": "",
            "email": "",
            "branch_id": 1,
            "Branch_by_branch_id": {
                "id": 1,
                "institution_id": 1,
                "branch_name": "NAME"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Have classes like this:

```
public class BranchByBranchId
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int institution_id { get; set; }
    public string branch_name { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int branch_id { get; set; }
    public BranchByBranchId Branch_by_branch_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Record> record { get; set; }
}
```

Then parse it and retrieve the value like this.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var branchName = root[0].Branch_by_branch_id.branch_name;
```

I always prefer to access my JSON objects like this, because I like having my objects as native C# classes. The classes were generated by [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

Comment: Hi Mason, will try this out. I take it the root index has to be changed for a integer variable so I can get the records of each loop kight?

Comment: @LordRelix Yes, or you could do something like `foreach(var  record in root.record) { Console.WriteLine(record.Branch_by_branch_id.branch_name); }`